# Fail in converting from SharpDX bitmap to GorgonImage

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I use [Gorgon](https://github.com/Tape-Worm/Gorgon) 2D library (built base on SharpDX) in my project. I got problem in converting from SharpDX bitmap to GorgonImage. I post my problem here and hope you guys can help me to solve it. Thanks

I use this code to create a SharpDX bitmap:

```
private GorgonImage D2DBitmapToGorgonImage(this SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap1 bm, SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext5 D2D1Context5)
{
    SharpDX.DataRectangle map;
    if (bm.Options == SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.Target)
    {
        var img1 = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap1(D2D1Context5, new SharpDX.Size2(bm.PixelSize.Width, bm.PixelSize.Height), new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapProperties1()
        {
            PixelFormat = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied),
            DpiX = 96,
            DpiY = 96,
            BitmapOptions = SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.CannotDraw | SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.CpuRead
        });

        img1.CopyFromBitmap(bm, new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawPoint(0, 0), new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawRectangle(0, 0, bm.PixelSize.Width, bm.PixelSize.Height));

        map = img1.Map(SharpDX.Direct2D1.MapOptions.Read);

        img1.Unmap();
        img1.Dispose();
    }

    else if (bm.Options == (SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.CannotDraw | SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.CpuRead))
        map = bm.Map(SharpDX.Direct2D1.MapOptions.Read);
    else
        throw new Exception("Can not convert from Direc2D1.Bitmap1 to GorgonImage");

    var size = bm.PixelSize.Width * bm.PixelSize.Height * 4;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy(map.DataPointer, bytes, 0, size);

    IGorgonImageInfo info = new GorgonImageInfo(ImageType.Image2D, BufferFormat.R8G8B8A8_UNorm)
    {
        Width = bm.PixelSize.Width,
        Height = bm.PixelSize.Height,

    };
    GorgonImage nqi = new GorgonImage(info);

    unsafe
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < info.Height; y++)
        {
            // We only need the width here, as our pointer will handle the stride by virtue of being an int.
            //int* offset = pixels + (y * bitmapLock.Width);

            int destOffset = y * nqi.Buffers[0].PitchInformation.RowPitch;
            for (int x = 0; x < info.Width; x++)
            {
                var position = (y * info.Width + x) * 4;


                byte r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, alpha = bytes[position + 3];
                if(bm.PixelFormat.AlphaMode == SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied)
                {
                    if (alpha != 0)
                    {
                        var div_alpha = 0xff00 / alpha;
                        r = (byte)((bytes[position] * div_alpha + 0x80) >> 8);
                        g = (byte)((bytes[position + 1] * div_alpha + 0x80) >> 8);
                        b = (byte)((bytes[position + 2] * div_alpha + 0x80) >> 8);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    r = bytes[position+1];
                    g = bytes[position+2];
                    b = bytes[position+3];
                }

                SharpDX.Color4 cl4 = new SharpDX.Color4((float)r/255.0f, (float)g/255.0f, (float)b/255.0f, (float)alpha/255.0f);
                // The DXGI format nomenclature is a little confusing as we tend to think of the layout as being highest to 
                // lowest, but in fact, it is lowest to highest.
                // So, we must convert to ABGR even though the DXGI format is RGBA. The memory layout is from lowest 
                // (R at byte 0) to the highest byte (A at byte 3).
                // Thus, R is the lowest byte, and A is the highest: A(24), B(16), G(8), R(0).

                int* destBuffer = (int*)(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref nqi.Buffers[0].Data[destOffset]));
                *destBuffer = cl4.ToRgba(); //color.ToABGR();
                //offset++;
                destOffset += 4;
            }
        }
    }
    return nqi;
}
```

Problem is, with SharpDX Bitmaps with size (**1280**,720). Converted Image is OK:

[image]

But with SharpDX Bitmaps with size (**1281**,720). The convert function does not work right. I got this converted image:

[image]

I can not find out what i was wrong with my code. Can you guys help to point me the problem? Thanks

These are types of Gorgon i used:

[`GorgonImage`](https://github.com/Tape-Worm/Gorgon/blob/master/Gorgon/Gorgon.Graphics.Imaging/GorgonImage.cs)
[`GorgonImageInfo`](https://github.com/Tape-Worm/Gorgon/blob/master/Gorgon/Gorgon.Graphics.Imaging/GorgonImageInfo.cs)
[`GorgonImageBuffer`](https://github.com/Tape-Worm/Gorgon/blob/master/Gorgon/Gorgon.Graphics.Imaging/GorgonImageBuffer.cs)
[`GorgonNativeBuffer`](https://github.com/Tape-Worm/Gorgon/blob/master/Gorgon/Gorgon.Core/Native/GorgonNativeBuffer.cs)

Comment: Is the data correct after the `Marshal.Copy` step? It didn't take `map.Pitch` into account so it looks a little fishy to me, but idk.

Comment: @harold
I changed 
var size = bm.PixelSize.Width * bm.PixelSize.Height * 4;

To:
var size = bm.PixelSize.Height * map.Pitch; 

Then copy:
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
Marshal.Copy(map.DataPointer, bytes, 0, size);

But the result does not get better

Comment: Did it change the result or not even that?

Comment: @harold It did not change the result

Comment: What about `(y * info.Width + x) * 4`, shouldn't that be a stride? Something like `y * stride + 4 * x`

Comment: @harold how can i calculate the stride value?

Comment: It would be the source stride so `map.Pitch`

Comment: @harold Who are you in this world? You save my life again. Thank you so much!

Comment: @harold please add your answer and i will mark

Comment: I added some explanation as well. By the way you don't need that whole `SharpDX.Color4` thing with the float divisions, you can stuff those r g b a bytes into the destination.

Comment: @harold: can tell me in details ?  "you can stuff those r g b a bytes into the destination"

Comment: Something like `nqi.ImageData[destOffset] = r; nqi.ImageData[destOffset + 1] = g;` etc for `b` and `a`, I think that's it

Comment: @harold yes, i will try it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @harold yes, it works like charm. Thank you so much!!!!  (heart heart heart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such skewing with wrapping is typically a stride vs width problem. You can use the direction of the skew (in combination with the row order, usually top down but not always) to see whether it's a problem in the source address calculations or the destination address calculations. Here the skew is angled "backwards", meaning the src address is advancing too slowly and as a result pixels end up further and further to the right and downward compared to where they should be. In principle the same effect could be caused by the destination address advancing too quickly, but that is less likely (a stride vs width problem wouldn't do that, using the *wrong* stride might)

So it would be `position` that is wrong, and `(y * info.Width + x) * 4` uses a width instead of a stride which is suspicious.

The source stride is `map.Pitch` so `position` should be `y * map.Pitch + 4 * x`